# JQuery Flexigrid plug-in in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I've got an ASP.Net project with C# and have a Repeater Control on an aspx page that builds up an html table by iterating over a datasource.  I want to use the JQuery Flexigrid plug-in to make the table scrollable, but have been unable to figure out how to make it work due to lack of documentation on the plug-in.  Does anyone know how to do this, or have sample code to share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used Flexigrid myself however after looking at the samples on the site I'll offer my suggestions.

It looks like what you need to create with your repeater is a properly formatted html table with at least a thead and tbody section.

```
<table id="mytable">
  <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>table data 1</td>
        <td>table data 2</td>
      <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Once done, making a simple call to the following should create the Flexigrid table with the default settings:

```
$("#mytable").flexigrid();
```

From there you can pass in what looks to be a ton of options to make it look as pretty as you want.

As for the repeater itself, there are a bunch of ways to set it up depending on what you need.  Probably the simplest way is as follows:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><asp:label id="header1" runat="server"></asp:label></th>
    <th><asp:label id="header2" runat="server"></asp:label></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<asp:repeater id="myrepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="myrepeater_ItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:label id="data1" runat="server"></asp:label></td>
      <td><asp:label id="data2" runat="server"></asp:label></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And your data bind event would look something like this:

```
public void myrepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  myDataObject = e.Item.DataItem;
  Label data1 = e.Item.FindControl("data1");
  Label data2 = e.Item.FindControl("data2");

  data1.Text = myDataObject.data1;
  data2.Text = myDataObject.data2;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying to do, with no success.  The call to create the flexigrid table needs to be wrapped in in the document ready function like below, or it doesn't do anything.  But when I run the code I get an Invalid argument error message.

       $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.flex1').flexigrid();
       });

Comment: I've tested his examples with quite a few variations regarding jQuery version, $(document).ready usage, removing thead and tbody tags, and nothing seems to be throwing any errors.  Take a look at the source code of your page and ensure that the table is properly formatted.

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search "asp.net+flexigrid" gave me [this](http://webdevdotnet.blogspot.com/2008/07/flexigrid.html) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FlexiGrid.aspx)

I must also mention that support looks to be thin on the ground for flexigrid so you maybe better looking at the better documented [jqGrid](http://trirand.com/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to reference the table by `id`, you're better off using a class to identify the table.  If you look at the page source you'll see that the table id isn't `mytable` - it's mangled by ASP.NET depending on your page structure.